# Determining Outlook Feature Support

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Is there a way to  determine in a VSTO add-in at run time if a feature is supported by Outlook? More specifically we'd like to test if the installed version of Office supports File/Email protection.

Previously we relied on the version of Office that is installed compared to what Microsoft said on their site. But that technique doesn't work well when they are adding new versions and change what their business editions support and do not support.